# PHP Libraries: SVN Access

Tags: php, svn

Are there any decent PHP libraries available for accessing SVN repositories? Right now I just have some scripts executing commands to the command line and parsing the feedback, I'd love to find something less dependent on the command line and more tightly integrated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google search;

https://www.php.net/svn
http://php-svn-client.tigris.org
http://pecl.php.net/package/svn

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fine just the way you are.   WebSvn, from websvn.tigris.org, the Subversion people themselves, does it the same way.   I also shell out to the command line and parse the responses in my app BugTracker.NET.